# Explicitly Using @2x images in an iPad xib in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, interface-builder, retina-display

I've got 2 sets of images in my project, one set for old displays and one @2x set for retina displays. I'm working on the iPad xibs (it's a universal app) and the double sized images that are @2x would actually work just fine for the ipad. If the image.png is 300 pixels wide, the image@2x.png is 600 pixels wide, so on the 768 wide iPad screen that would work just fine. When I put a UIImageView in my iPad xib, I try to set the Image Name to explicitly be image@2x.png, but I get the ?? image which means that Interface Builder doesn't know what it is.

When I launch the simulator it does actually show the @2x image, so it is technically working, but Interface Builder won't show it to me properly and that makes it difficult to create the layout.

Is there a way to get Interface Builder to show me the @2x image when I'm making an iPad xib?

Comment: Pretty sure that this can be added to the list of IB annoyances with umiversal apps.  Unless you add duplicate images with a different name for testing and alignment, then erase them and switch to the @2x when you're done, it wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it works is that Interface Builder automatically chooses the right one for your device. You cannot explicitly change that as it is against its existence.

Answer (score 1):

Images can be named with a ~iPad to specify that they should be used when running on the iPad.  For example, you could have these images:
myImage.png
myImage@2x.png
myImage~iPad.png

The first will get used on the iPhone 3GS and below, the second on the iPhone 4, and the third on the iPad.

Comment: Right, but that's not the point. I don't want to name them ~ipad (btw, it needs to be lowercase), because I want them to be automatically used for the retina displays. I don't want to have a third set of images (1 for iPhone, 2nd for retina, then 3rd for iPad) because the retina images would work perfectly. I just can't get IB to let me use the @2x images in my xibs.